# Why this refers to global object?

Tags: javascript

I have this code:

```
function F() {
  function C() {
    return this;
  }
  return C();
}
var o = new F();
```

Can someone explain why `this` refers to the global object and not to the `function C` when create the object `o`? Maybe this is happening because when create the new object `o`, evokes the function `C` which now `this` belongs to global object?

Comment: https://www.google.com/webhp#q=javascript+understanding+this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You never set C() to be a member of F(), so C() is just a global function. I got it working by creating C() as a child of F() like this:

```
function F() {
  this.C = function() {
    return this;
  }
  return this.C();
}
var o = new F();
```

Comment: if i change my OP to `function F() { function C() { return this; } return C;
} var o = new F();` then new object `o` will have the function `C`.

Comment: Did you want it to return C? I misunderstood... :(

Comment: No i don't want to return C. Just want to know why returns the global object and not the function C? I almost get it :)

Comment: Thanks for your effort Chris. Really appreciated. Already upvoted :)

Answer (score 1):

It essentially comes down to constructing the function or not. When you do `new F()` you're constructing a new function object which you can use `this` on to reference itself. You can achieve the same result you were getting by just trying:

```
function F() {
  return this
}

var o = F();
```

Doing this will just return the global window object because `F()` wasn't constructed. To get the result you were expecting, you can do what @ChrisGimas suggested, which would keep the context of the outer constructed function, or you can construct the inner as well:

```
function F() {
  function C() {
    return this;
  }
  return new C();
}
var o = new F();
```